# Removing bad data (same device ID and timestamp, 2 different values) from a dataframe

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I'm pulling data that has a device ID, a timestamp, and a value. I'll have lots of different device ID's and data points for each hour of the day across an entire month. If I have two pieces of data with the same ID and the same Time, but different Values, how can I remove the lower of the two (which would just be bad data)? Alternatively, I can do this step further below. I'm not sure which would be easier.

Here's an example of the data I'd be working with.

```
       ID        Time                   Value
1234   64058     2022-03-23 08:00:00    1014.98
1235   64059     2022-03-23 08:00:00    1001.34
1236   64060     2022-03-23 08:00:00    1001.52
1237   64061     2022-03-23 08:00:00    1483.11
1238   64062     2022-03-23 08:00:00    1342.23
1239   64063     2022-03-23 08:00:00    1201.34
1242   64058     2022-03-23 08:00:00    10.55
```

To make the data easier to see, I merge it with another dataframe that has actual device names rather than just ID's and then pivot it to a wider format with this.

```
av_device_merge <- merge(av_data, device_list, by.av_data = ID, by.device_list = ID) %>%  select(-c(ID)

pivoted <- av_device_merge %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Device_Short_Name, values_from = Value)
```

Which yields this result (just including the one hour as an example):

```
Time                    Device 1              Device 2    Device 3    Device 4    Device 5    Device 6
2022-03-23 08:00:00     c(1014.98, 10.55)     1001.34     1001.52     1483.11     1342.23     1201.34
2022-03-23 09:00:00
...
```

This is the part where I could also look at each column, and if the data present is a vector, then keep the highest value only and change to a numeric value.

Which of the two would be easier to do? I'm guessing the first option? Any ideas on how to accomplish this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `library(dplyr); av_data %>% group_by(ID, Time) %>% filter(Value == max(Value)) %>% ungroup()`, or if it's possible you could have duplicate values, you could `arrange(-Value) %>% slice(1)` after `group_by` to ensure only one entry per ID/Time is kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this

```
data %>%
    group_by(ID, Time) %>%
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Value, with_ties = FALSE)

data %>%
    group_by(ID, Time)%>%
    top_n(1, wt = Value)
```

I prefer slice_max and the with_ties = FALSE in case of identical values.